# Objective-C / Sprite kit: Multiple scenes with the same *dynamic* background?

Tags: objective-c, menu, background, sprite-kit, scene

I'm working on the main menu for a game I've started developing (learning SK at the same time, so this may be a stupid question).  What I'd like to have happen is one of two things:

1. Have code for scenes (main menu, options, about, select file, etc.) in their own respective files (subclass of SKScene).
2. Have scenes all present on the same file, for which the view would simply scroll to the left or right when a button is pressed (i.e.: press options, all content scrolls to right to display content of the options screen).

I understand that these options alone aren't difficult to accomplish, but here's my snag:  Ideally, I'd like to have sprites displayed doing various things in the background of these pages (what they're doing won't depend on what page is being viewed).  If I understand all of this well enough, option 1 would reset the background, so sprites would suddenly disappear during the scene transition - which is what led me to option 2.

However, I'm having difficulty figuring out how to accomplish option 2 efficiently.  Best I've thought of is to declare SKNode for every element of every menu screen which sounds terribly inefficient.

So, in summary: I need a way to switch between various screens without changing scenes so I can preserve sprite activity going on in the background  Is there something I can do to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/29372723/2158465